# Sublime 3 - Java build system for specific project

Tags: java, sublimetext3, javac, build-system

I want to have a simple project in Sublime Text 3 where I can press `⌘B` on my Mac, and all my `Java` files will be built, and the currently open `Java` file is run. I have accomplished this in the past by going to `Tools > Build System > New Build System...` and creating a system-level build file. After having done this, I will see the build system in the `Tools > Build System` menu.

However, I want to have a project-specific build system (so that it doesn't clutter my system level settings). I tried to accomplish this by creating a new project file under `Project > Save Project As...`. This created a project-level file into which I pasted the following:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",
            "name": "java-run-system"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
    },
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "java-run-system",
            "shell_cmd": "javac *.java && java -ea $file_base_name",
            "selector": "source.java",
            "file_regex": "^\\s*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I do this though, I don't see the `java-run-system` I made in the `Tools > Build System` menu